# Running a JFXDialog when a application starts

Tags: java, xml, javafx

Currently I'm making a Client Server chat GUI to send and receive messages. What I want is when the application starts up, a JFXDialog opens up and asks for Username, Firstname, Lastname and the Server IP address. **I managed to make one in the controller class in the initialize method**. I made a fxml for the JFXDialog that I would like to use instead (to shorten up code in the controller class). Is there a way to do this?

JFXDialog is from **JFoenix**

All the code is located in [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/Clumsy-Coder/bc00ec884a7e8e1cd394d1f4964d1d30)

ClientChatController.java is the controller class.

clientGUI.fxml is the main GUI file that contains all the elements to be displayed.

dialog.fxml is the file is needed to be used instead of hardcoded values in the controller class.

Currently the hardcoded code in ClientChatController.java is working. I want to replace it with the dialog.fxml file. The dialog should shows up when the application starts.

From what I know the JFXDialog needs to be the child of StackPane.

NOTE: the reason not posting the code on StackOverFlow is because it's easier to see it on Github Gist.

Controller class

```
public class ClientChatController implements Initializable
{
    private ArrayList<Label> users = new ArrayList<Label>();
    @FXML
    private JFXListView<Label> userList;
    @FXML
    private JFXListView<Label> conversationList;
    @FXML
    private StackPane stackPane;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextField username;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextField firstname;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextField lastname;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextField serverIP;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {

        //open dialog that contains text field for username, firstname,
        //lastname and server IP address

        JFXDialogLayout content = new JFXDialogLayout();
        content.setHeading(new Text("Setup"));
        VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
        vbox.getChildren()
            .addAll(username, firstname, lastname, serverIP);
        content.setBody(vbox);
        JFXDialog dialog = new JFXDialog(stackPane, content, JFXDialog.DialogTransition.CENTER);
        JFXButton button = new JFXButton("Connect");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println("Username: " + username.getText());
                System.out.println("Firstname: " + firstname.getText());
                System.out.println("Lastname: " + lastname.getText());
                System.out.println("ServerIP: " + serverIP.getText());
                dialog.close();
            }
        });

        content.setActions(button);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void clientSetup(ActionEvent event)
    {
        //NOT BEING USED AT THE MOMENT
        System.out.println("Username: " + username);
        System.out.println("Firstname: " + firstname);
        System.out.println("Lastname: " + lastname);
        System.out.println("ServerIP: " + serverIP);
    }
}
```

fxml used for displaying the content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
    <StackPane fx:id="stackPane"
                xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112-ea"
                xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
                fx:controller="client.gui.ClientChatController">
        <BorderPane >
           <left>
               <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true"
                           fitToWidth="true">
                   <content>
                       <JFXListView fx:id="userList"/>
                   </content>
               </ScrollPane>
           </left>
           <right>
               <BorderPane>
                   <center>
                       <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true">
                           <content>
                               <JFXListView fx:id="conversationList"/>
                           </content>
                       </ScrollPane>
                   </center>
                   <bottom>
                       <BorderPane>
                           <padding>
                               <Insets bottom="5"
                                       top="1"/>
                           </padding>
                           <center>
                               <JFXTextArea fx:id="textArea"
                                            maxHeight="92"
                                            maxWidth="450"
                                            promptText="Type message"
                                            disable="true">
                               </JFXTextArea>
                           </center>
                           <right>
                               <JFXButton fx:id="sendBtn"
                                          alignment="CENTER"
                                          buttonType="FLAT"
                                          disable="true"
                                             maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                          maxWidth="110.0"
                                          ripplerFill="#4059a9"
                                          text="Send"
                                          textAlignment="CENTER">
                               </JFXButton>
                           </right>
                       </BorderPane>
                   </bottom>
               </BorderPane>
           </right>
       </BorderPane>
    </StackPane>
```

dialog.xml the file I would to use instead of hardcoded code in ClientChatController.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<StackPane
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2"
        fx:controller="client.gui.ClientChatController">
    <JFXDialog fx:id="setupDialog">
        <JFXDialogLayout>
            <heading>
                <Label>Setup</Label>
            </heading>
            <body>
                <VBox spacing="10">
                    <JFXTextField fx:id="username"
                                  promptText="Username"
                                  maxWidth="20">

                    </JFXTextField>
                    <JFXTextField fx:id="firstName"
                                  promptText="First name"
                                  maxWidth="20">

                    </JFXTextField>
                    <JFXTextField fx:id="lastname"
                                  promptText="Last name"
                                  maxWidth="20">

                    </JFXTextField>
                    <JFXTextField fx:id="serverIP"
                                  promptText="Server IP address"
                                  maxWidth="20">

                    </JFXTextField>
                </VBox>
            </body>
            <actions>
                <JFXButton fx:id="connectBtn">Connect</JFXButton>
            </actions>
        </JFXDialogLayout>
    </JFXDialog>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: I don't know JFoenix, and their site doesn't seem to have any Javadocs readily accessible, so I can't provide a definite answer, but there seem to be two mistakes here. 1. Don't use the same controller class for two different FXML files; create a controller class for each one. 2. It seems unlikely that it makes sense to place a `JFXDialog` inside a `StackPane`. What are you actually intending to do there?

Comment: 1) My intention is to get the username, firstname, lastname and server IP and pass it to the back end to connect to the server. So I'm not sure how to do it in another way. This will be the first thing you need to do before you can connect to the server.
2) JFXDialog is from **JFoenix** JavaFX library. I looked up a video about it. It says that you need StackPane as the parent, in order for it to work

Comment: I was assuming that a class with "Dialog" in the name was a subclass of `Stage` or `Window`, in which case it wouldn't make sense (wouldn't be possible) to put it in a `StackPane`. But again, no Javadocs (unless you can provide a link to them), so no way to tell without installing the library or trawling through the source code.

Comment: And, to re-emphasize, it's basically always a mistake to use the same controller class for two different FXML files. You need to start by creating different controllers for each FXML.

Comment: Unfortunately, the JavaDocs can only be obtained by cloning the [GIthub repo](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) and running `./gradlew javadoc` command (assuming you're running on Linux or Mac). The JavaDocs would be located in `subprojects/jfoenix/build/docs/javadoc`